# ModuleNotFound Error while import custom python package

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks

I have my project file sitting in the path */Workspace/folder1/subfolder1/myproject*

This is how I have structured my project files:

[image]

**Structure of Module folder:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0ecB.png)

baseMLPipeline is my entry file where I am importing the file in the modules directory. I have .py files along with **init**.py file in modules folder.

When I run the baseMLPipeline notebook on databricks, it works fine and is importing the custom package successfully. However, when I trigger this notebook from ADF (using job cluster), it throws a **"ModuleNotFound"** error. Is there something that I a missing or doing wrong?

The code throws the error at line where I am importing the custom package

```
from modules import test_1
```

Below are the steps that I have already tried:

1. Moved the modules folder in same directory containing the main notebook i.e. */Workspace/folder1/subfolder1/myproject* .
2. Created an empty file called **init**.py in the same directory as my .py files.
3. In the notebook, added the following code at the beginning to add the *Workspace/folder1/subfolder1/myproject* folder to the Python path:

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.append("Workspace/folder1/subfolder1/myproject")
   ```

Comment: @JayashankarGS added the structure for modules. The modules containes the python files which i am trying to import in the baseMLPipeline notebook.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a new **Job Cluster**, it gives this error because it does not have the **Users** and **Shared** folders under **Workspace** like what you have.

[image]

So, this is the reason it is working in **All-purpose compute** in Databricks and not in **Job compute** (New Job Cluster) in ADF.

In ADF, you check **Existing interactive cluster** and select your existing **All-purpose compute**.

[image]

Or, you can create a new repository with all your files and notebooks in **Repo** and run it with a new job cluster.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason your job is failing is because your custom modules aren't in the PYTHONPATH of your job cluster. Run `%sh echo $PYTHONPATH` in both an interactive notebook and in a job cluster and you'll see that databricks adds the Workspace folder to your python PATH only in an interactive cluster.

Unfortunately there's no way to update your python path in an init script or something, it has to be set in the same session as your job script: https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/set-pythonpath-when-executing-workflows/m-p/11840/highlight/true#M6755

Your #3 attempt should work, I believe you just need to prepend the path with a slash. Add this to the top of your notebook:

```
import os
import sys


if os.getenv("DB_IS_JOB_CLUSTER"):
    sys.path.append("/Workspace/folder1/subfolder1/myproj")
```

You can use the env var `DB_IS_JOB_CLUSTER` which databricks adds to the cluster environment.